# Good places to start for Calculus?

Tags: calculus

I am a student, and due to my school's decision to not teach Calculus in high school (They said we'd learn it in college, but that's a year and a half away for me), I have to learn it myself. I am trying to get a summer internship as a Bioinformatics intern, and I would like to have prior knowledge (I was told I'd need an understanding of calculus to get the internship.)

I have heard of MIT's OpenCourseWare, which I had taken a look at, but I was wondering if there were any other resources (Preferably free of charge, I don't have much money to spend)

Is there any good online (Preferably free) way to learn Calculus?

Comment: [Pauls' online notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/CalcI.aspx) should be a decent one.

Comment: (Patrick JMT)[http://patrickjmt.com/] is also a good one. His videos are a little faster paced than Khan's, which I personally think is a good thing.

Comment: This isn't a way to learn calculus, but rather to test your conceptual understanding of the material. [This website](http://www.dougshaw.com/findtheerror/) offers a bunch of fake proofs of ridiculous claims ($\sin x > 0$ for all $x$, $0 = 1$, etc.) using calculus, and you have to try to find what the error is. I've found it to be fun and useful for developing logical careful thinking in mathematics at a lower level.

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at the [Khan Academy?](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/calculus)
There are tutorials for just about every topic in Calculus, particularly if you're just beginning to learn Calculus.

> Topics covered in the first two or three semesters of college calculus. Everything from limits to derivatives to integrals to vector calculus. Should understand the topics in the pre-calculus playlist first (the limit videos are in both playlists)

[MIT OpenCourseWare](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01-single-variable-calculus-fall-2006/video-lectures/) (Link to Calculus: single-variable, with lecture videos) can give you a nice outline of what topics to master, and how to progress through these topics, and includes video lectures, as well as handouts you can download.

Another great resource is [Paul's Notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/CalcI.aspx), which is presented as a progressive tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

Try this site, it's interesting [math doctor bob](http://www.mathdoctorbob.org/).

Answer (score 1):

MIT OpenCourseWare is useful. Also, check out Paul's Online Notes:

http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/CalcI.aspx

Answer (score 1):

www.openculture.com/freeonlinecourses

www.coursera.org/courses

Coursera comes with problem sets, the lectures are paced, and you can discuss things with your classmates on the associated forums.

Answer (score 0):

Go online and order a calculus book from an older edition. My advice, take Stewart Calculus. The current edition is the 7th, thus expensive, even used. Purchase the 6th edition that can be had for a nickel and a dime and you got yourself an excellent resource.
Along with the websites listed by my colleagues, you can get quite far.